# How to use Common Table Expression For multiple columns SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization, common-table-expression

I have a query as:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT AIP.aid [Author_ID], CAST(P.research_area as VARCHAR(100)) [Research_Area], 
       P.research_area_category_id [Category], COUNT(*) [Paper_Count], 
       P.p_year [Paper_Year]
FROM author_individual_papers AIP
JOIN sub_aminer_paper P ON AIP.pid = P.pid
WHERE AIP.aid IN (SELECT aid FROM Authors) AND P.p_year = 2005
GROUP BY AIP.aid, CAST(P.research_area as VARCHAR(100)),
         P.research_area_category_id, P.p_year
),
CTE1 AS
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Author_ID ORDER BY Paper_Count DESC) AS Rank
 FROM CTE
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE1
WHERE Rank <= 3
```

This gives output as:

```
Author_ID   Research_Area   Category    Paper_Count Paper_Year  Rank
677         probabilistic   12          1           2005        1
677         feature extract 8           1           2005        2
677         image annotate  11          1           2005        3
1359        image represent 11          2           2005        1
1359        kernel method   14          1           2005        2
1359        data grid       8           1           2005        3
6242        info system     12          1           2005        1
6242        capable model   21          1           2005        2
6242        clustering      8           1           2005        3
8318        power manage    17          1           2005        1
...  
...
```

Now I want to have all this output for multiple years i.e. `P.p_year` ranging between `2005` to `2014`. But If I use `P.p_year BETWEEN 2005 AND 2014`, then it mixes the output as it takes the `Paper_Count` for whole ten years then ranks them whereas I need separately ranked for each `P.p_year` and for each `Author_ID`

Comment: To rank separately for each `P.p_year` use: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Author_ID, [Paper_Year] ...`

Comment: Also, `COUNT(*) [Paper_Count]` should be giving you the correct result as  you are already grouping by `P.p_year`.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I am using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Author_ID, [Paper_Year] ...` in query. Are you suggesting same or something else???

Comment: You are using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Author_ID ORDER BY Paper_Count DESC)`, not `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Author_ID, [Paper _year] ORDER BY Paper_Count DESC)`

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Thanks now I got it

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos can we convert it as creating new columns i.e. ten more columns for `P.p_year` 2005-2014 and storing corresponding values in these columns

Comment: If you need additional *columns* instead of additional *rows*, then you have to use *conditional aggregation*, like `... COUNT(CASE WHEN P.p_year = 2015 THEN 1 END ) [Paper_Count_2015], COUNT(CASE WHEN P.p_year = 2016 THEN 1 END ) [Paper_Count_2016]  ...`

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I need the value of `Category` in newly created columns and also there should be `3` rows for each `Author_ID` but here it is giving more i.e. for each year